# Install facebook SDK on react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, facebook-javascript-sdk, react-native-ios

I'm currently trying to install the Facebook SDK on my app, but it seems to be very complicated. Apparently, facebook SDK is no longer available on react native? So how can I install the SDK on my app ?
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can try:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fbsdk-next

Is the same concept, however, held by the community.

Comment: Hey, thanks for yout anwser I will try this :)

Comment: Hi @Aroldo, it works fines on Android but not working on IOS.

Do you know any solution for this ?